# Overwrite or add a Picture to a Contact in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on an app that will add an image to contacts with one, or may overwrite a picture if one already exists, per user settings.

I am to the part where I need to actually write the cached image to the contact, but am unsure how to go about doing this?

Can I simply overwrite the image at the `PHOTO_URI`, or is there some method I have to call to update the picture?

```
cacheDir = Home.this.getCacheDir() + File.separator + "download"
            + File.separator;

contactId[contactList.getPosition()] = contactList
            .getString(contactList
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

contactPicture[contactList.getPosition()] = contactList
            .getString(contactList
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

downloadFile = new File(cacheDir
            + contactId[contactList.getPosition()] + ".png");

FileManager.copyFile(downloadFile, new File( //Custom function - just copies
            contactPicture[contactList.getPosition()]));
```

I have not yet run this code, because I do not want to screw up my contact list.

Is this the correct way of overwriting a contact picture? Also, what if a picture does not already exist, and the `PHOTO_URI` is `null`? How do I go about adding a new image?

Comment: refer this one maybe helpfull  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112272/how-to-update-contact-image-using-contact-provider-operation/18118617#18118617