# There is no error but still can't change phone contact image

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-contacts

I'm quit scared with this application. I'm developing an application that changes the contact photo with from image-view. It doesn't generate any error but does not even change contact image. I have a doubt, if it's the OnActivityResult() method. Please correct me on that. Here is the code of OnActivityResult() method.

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
        switch (requestCode) {
        case IMAGE_PICK:    
            this.imageFromGallery(resultCode, data);
            break;
        case IMAGE_CAPTURE:
            this.imageFromCamera(resultCode, data);
            break;
         case PICK_PHOTO:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){ 

                    // Getting the uri of the picked photo
                    Uri updateImageView = data.getData();

                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        // Getting InputStream of the selected image
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(updateImageView);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Creating bitmap of the selected image from its inputstream
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                    // Getting reference to ImageView
                   // ImageButton ibPhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photo);

                    // Setting Bitmap to ImageButton
                    photo.setImageBitmap(image);
                } 
                break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

> also here is my onClick() code.

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                    new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

             int position=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("bmp");
            int po=ops.size();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

              if(image!=null)
              { // If an image is selected successfully
                  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG , 100, stream);



               //   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                  image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG , 75, stream);

                  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, position) // here position is _ID where I'm inserting image
                             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,stream.toByteArray())
                             .build());

                      try {
                           stream.flush();

                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }      

              }  
              else
              {
                  Log.d("Image Null", "True");
              }
              try{

                  // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                  getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,ops);
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact Image change successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();

              }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }             
            }       });
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112272/how-to-update-contact-image-using-contact-provider-operation/18118617#18118617

Comment: dear in which place i'm doing correction..?? @Aravin